# while installing aws amplify init on terminal .gives error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

i am getting this while doing amplify init , so main agenda is to develop authentication through aws-cognito , which is using aws-amplify,

```
? Do you want to use an AWS profile? Yes
? Please choose the profile you want to use default
init failed
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27) {
  message: 'read ECONNRESET',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  syscall: 'read',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: 'amplify.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2020-04-16T12:09:59.975Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following strategies to eliminate the problem you are facing,

1. This more of looks like a Network problem as per the logs from your
   Terminal, therefore if you have a jittery connection, I would
   recommend that you try the same on a stable internet connection.
2. I will recommend to do an amplify delete in case there is some mis-configuration from the last time you did an amplify init, but the chances of this are very less.
3. Check your aws environment variables or configuration file maybe the credentials of your aws account are missing. Try doing an aws configure and reset the values of your key,secret, and region.

I hope the above suggestions help you somehow.